# Python reqeusts get with params that are ISO datetime not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests

I am having trouble getting the requests library for python to work with ISO datetime parameters

```
headers = {"Authorization: Token [token_here]"}
body = {"start_date": "2019-07-01T05:00:00Z","end_date": "2019-07-02T00:00:00Z"}
resp = requests.get("https://website.com/api/v1/endpoint", headers=headers, params=body)
```

The above will turn the url into the following

```
https://website.com/api/v1/endpoint?%7B%22start_date%22:%20%222019-07-01T05:00:00Z%22,%20%22end_date%22:%20%222019-07-03T00:00:00Z%22%7D'
```

which results in a 405 for me. However, using the exact same body in body.json for httpie works fine

```
cat body.json

{"start_date": "2019-07-01T05:00:00Z","end_date": "2019-07-02T00:00:00Z"}

http https://website.com/api/v1/endpoint 'Authorization: Token [token_here]' < body.json
```

Comment: “Body” is different from “params” - params are added to the URL as ?name1=value1&name2=value2... Whereas body is the body of an http post, i.e. something completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON should be sent as the body of a POST request. For that you can use the convenient `json` parameter of the `requests.post` method:

```
resp = requests.post("https://website.com/api/v1/endpoint", headers=headers, json=body)
```